# Запуск следующего итератора цикла в Asynctask-e при нажатии на кнопку на андроиде

Tags: java, android, activity, android-asynctask

В андроиде необходимо сделать выполнение каждого итератора в цикле при нажатии на кнопку. Имеется код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
int i = 0;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    state = savedInstanceState;
button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
......

  new MyAsynctask().execute();
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

   i++;
    this.onCreate(state);
}

 class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

 for (;i<array.size;){
     ...........
    return null;
    }
 }
```

В OnCreate элементы заполняются динамически.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку срабатывало обновление OnCreate но при этом значение i  не терялось.То есть чтобы цикл выполнялся  сначала с i=0. При нажатии на кнопку с i=1 и т. д.
    При вызове this.onCreate(state);  метод onCreate перезапускается но i все равно остается нулевым. При этом Asznctasc  важен так как там выполняется вся другая сложная работа помимо цикла. Какие идеи?
Спасибо!

Comment: `onCreate` выполняется только один раз, при создании активити и ему глубоко безразлично, сколько раз надо вам, чтобы он выполнялся. Ознакомьтесь с жизненным циклом активити до полного понимания, как работают ее методы обратного вызова и для чего их можно переопределять - вызовать `onCreate`самому ,это за гранью разработки под платформу. Идея такая - продолжать изучать теорию и использовать проверенные паттерны программирования, а не придумывать адскую отсебятину

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы жизненного цикла активити, такие как: `onCreate` `onResume` `onPause` `onStop` и тд. вызываются **исключительно системой** с одной целью - чтобы программист мог выполнить какие то свои действия, когда активити находится в одном из соответствующих состояний: создается, восстановилась на экране, потеряла фокус , пропала с экрана и тд.
То есть, это работает так: если активити создается - сделать это, если активити потеряла фокус - сделать так и тп. Программист **не должен никаким образом самостоятельно влиять** на жизненный цикл активити.

Вся текущая бизнес-логика, которая действует в промежутке активности активити, которому соответствует состояние **между** `onResume` и `onPause` (видна на экране и получила фокус), инициализируется через **слушатели событий**, такие, как нажатия на виджеты на экране, повороты устройства, внешние сообщения системы и тд.
При этом реакцией на события должны быть не вмешательства в работу системы, а выполнение **собственных методов**, инициализация классов и пр.

В вашем случае вам надо объявить этот ваш итератор `i` полем класса и увеличивать его значение, написав **собственный метод** обработки этого итератора, который будет вызываться по событию клика на кнопку или же, если действия не многочислены - выполняться прямо в методе обратного вызова слушателя клика кнопки ( в методе `onClick`).
Также вам нужно позаботиться о сохранении значения итератора при изменениях конфигурации системы, например, поворот устройства , с помощью метода обратного вызова `onSaveInstanceState`

PS: надеюсь строки вроде: `class Asynctask() extends AsyncTask` , `int = 0;` - какие то опечатки потому, что такое компилятор никак не переварит.

Пока вы ненапридумывали еще какого то адского говонкода, рекомендую взять учебник по разработке под андроид и начинать читать его, до полного просветления - как это на самом деле делается. От себя могу порекомендовать:

> Брайн Харди , Билл Филипс - Программирование под Android - 2014

Comment: Не всегда методы жизненного цикла вызываются самой системой, точнее вызываются они системой, но Вы можете в некоторых случая инициировать некоторые действия. Например вызов метода finish. Но это просто дополнение.

Comment: Спасибо опечатки исправил. Но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку все изображение на экране менялось на новое. То есть у меня  там анкета с вопросами и при ответе на вопрос и при нажатии на кнопку "дальше"  должен появляться следующий вопрос а старый исчезать для этого мне нужно как то обновить этот вью при сохранении итератора. В настоящий момент при нажатии на кнопку активити пересоздается но показывает тот же результат что и прежде.

Comment: В ваших методах, обрабатывающих события слушателей, вы можете изменять первоначальное содержимое `View` с помощью методов-сеттеров этих `View` - например, в методе `onClick` вызвать `button.setText("На кнопку нажали");` - это приведет к тому, что после нажатия на кнопку надпись на кнопке изменится на "На кнопку нажали". Не мучайте себя беспродуктивными поисками решений, которые уже давно решены - почитайте книжку, как адекватные люди разрабатывают приложения.

Comment: Кстати , в предложенной мной книге детально рассматривается в том числе и разработка приложения-викторины - предлагаются вопросы и нужно вводить ответы. Разве это не то, что вам надо? и реализовано там именно так, как должно быть реализовано подобное приложение, с подробными пояснениями и комментариями - почему делается так, а не иначе.

Comment: спасибо, вы правы